# Типизация React + TS

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Прошу помощи с типизацией компонента. Суть:

имеется компонент A):
**Select.tsx:**

```
    export function Select(props: SelectProps) {
        const { labelId = "select-label", onChange, label, menuItems, ...rest } = props;
        const handleChange = useCallback(
            (event: SelectChangeEvent<unknown>) => {
              if (onChange) {
                onChange(event.target.value);
              }
            },
            [onChange],
          );
    }
```

интерфейсы:

```
 export interface SelectProps extends Omit<SelectPropsMui, "onChange"> {
  onChange?: (value: unknown) => void;
  Items: Item[];
}
```

В данный компонент я передаю:

```
const handleStatusSelect = useCallback(
    (value: string | unknown) => setStatus(value as string),
    [],
  );
```

...

```
<Select onChange={handleStatusSelect} />
```

Вопрос: правильно ли типизировано **value** в **handleStatusSelect**?

Answer (score -1):

У вас типизация `value` в `handleStatusSelect` не совсем корректна. Тип `value` должен соответствовать типу, который передается в колбек функцию `onChange` компонента `Select`. В интерфейсе `SelectProps` он определен как `unknown`, поэтому лучше изменить тип в `handleStatusSelect` на `unknown`

```
const handleStatusSelect = useCallback(
    (value: unknown) => setStatus(value as string),
    [],
  );
```

Лучше добавить проверку типа или явно преобразовать значение к строке перед использованием, чтобы не возникли ошибки.